# Check if file exists using Acrobat javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, file, exists, acrobat

I'm trying to determine if a specific .xml file exists on my desktop before running additional code. The following trusted script is in my Javascripts folder-level directory. The section commented as "First Part" below simply sets all fields of the form to be open/writable. The second part looks for a .xml file in which to import XFA data from.

My problem is that I'm trying to determine whether this .xml file exists in the first place. Right now if it doesn't exist, it displays a dialog window to browse for the file. **Instead I'd like it to show an alert if the xml file does not exist, and never show the dialog at all**. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is huge, thanks

**CODE:**

```
var myTrustFunctTwo = app.trustedFunction(function(doc)
{

//First Part
  for (var nPageCount = 0; nPageCount < doc.numPages; nPageCount++) {
        var oFields = doc.xfa.layout.pageContent(nPageCount, "field");
  //app.alert(oFields,0);
        var nNodesLength = oFields.length;
        // Set the field property.
        for (var nNodeCount = 0; nNodeCount < nNodesLength; nNodeCount++) {
            oFields.item(nNodeCount).access = "open";
        }
    }

//Second Part
app.beginPriv();
doc.importXFAData({
          cPath:"/c/Users/ME/Desktop/Filled_In.xml"
                 });
app.endPriv();
});
app.trustedFunction(myTrustFunctTwo);
```

**UPDATE CODE INCLUDING TRY/CATCH BLOCKS**

```
var myTrustFunctTwo = app.trustedFunction(function(doc) {

    for (var nPageCount = 0; nPageCount < doc.numPages; nPageCount++) {
        var oFields = doc.xfa.layout.pageContent(nPageCount, "field");
        //app.alert(oFields,0);
        var nNodesLength = oFields.length;
        // Set the field property.
        for (var nNodeCount = 0; nNodeCount < nNodesLength; nNodeCount++) {
            oFields.item(nNodeCount).access = "open";
        }
    }


    try {

        app.beginPriv();
        doc.importXFAData({
            cPath: "/c/Users/ME/Desktop/Filled_In.xml"
        });
        app.endPriv();

    } catch (e) {
        app.alert("No File Found", 1);
    }


});

app.trustedFunction(myTrustFunctTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file you try to import does not exist, you will get an error message. Using `try…catch`, you can catch that message and exit the function, thus prevent the subsequent code from running.

Comment: Thank you Max. I have updated my question to demonstrate the changes, but now what occurs is this: It enters the `try` block where it unsuccessfully finds the XML on the desktop, therefore I thought it'd enter the `catch` block but instead it still shows the dialog box... perhaps because the `doc.importXFAData` line invokes the dialog regardless(?). I need it to show an alert if file isn't found *not* show the dialog. Please help, thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: I ended up solving the problem with this code `app.beginPriv();
 this.importDataObject("myFile", "/c/Users/ME/Desktop/Filled_In.xml"); 
 var myData = this.getDataObject("myFile");`. This bypassed the instant dialog and displayed an error like you said it would. I used a catch block to perform the necessary alert. Thanks Max